# change the value of the second spinner on lost focus of the first spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have two spinners  on is district and another is cities i want to change the value of the cities spinner as the district changes. this is my code 
    taluka.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("on focus"+hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus==false)
        {
        String district= District.getSelectedItem().toString();
         if(district.equalsIgnoreCase("Ahmednagar"))
         {

                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Sign_up.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Ahmednagar_taluka));
                taluka.setAdapter(spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter);
         }
         else  if(district.equalsIgnoreCase("Akola"))
         {

                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Sign_up.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Akola_taluka));
                taluka.setAdapter(spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter);
         }
        }
    }

});
```

I am trying to do this on lost focus of first one.